# auto_ptr vs unique_ptr in containers & algorithms

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, containers, smart-pointers

I understand auto_ptr has screwed up copy semantics and therefore is not safe for use in containers since copying one auto_ptr to another will make the source = NULL pointer (isn't this like move semantics anyway??). But then again, unique_ptr cannot be copied at all and can only transfer ownership. So, how is unique_ptr usable in containers and algorithms that need to use copy operations to copy and re-arrange elements?

Comment: *"how is unique_ptr usable in containers and algorithms that need to use copy operations"* Not at all. But then again, many operations do not require copying. Re-arranging can be done via `swap` (and moves).

Comment: So, swap uses move semantics?

Comment: The new Standard Library generic swap is based on a move construction and two move assignments. But `unique_ptr` also provides a specialized version of that generic algorithm. In any way, a movable type is swappable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an in-depth explanation of why `auto_ptr` is dangerous, while `unique_ptr` is not:
[N1856 : Why deprecate auto_ptr?](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1856.html#20.4.5%20-%20Class%20template%20auto_ptr)

The main argument is that in generic code, something that has the syntax of a copy, should be a copy, not a move:

```
template <class It>
void sort(It first, It last)
{
    // ...
    value_type pivot_element = *mid_point;
    // ...
}
```

In the above example, the generic code is highly likely to have logic that demands that `pivot_element` and `*mid_point` be equivalent after the copy construction shown.  This may or may not be generic code in the `std::lib`.  It might be generic code you have written.

When `value_type` turns out to be a `std::auto_ptr<T>`, then the above code compiles, but the assumption that `pivot_element == *mid_point` fails.  A run-time error follows.

When `value_type` turns out to be a `std::unique_ptr<T>`, then the above code fails at compile-time (because you can't copy a `std::unique_ptr<T>`).  Thus use of `std::unique_ptr<T>` in preference to `std::auto_ptr<T>` effectively turns run time errors into compile-time errors.

Now it is also true that within the `std::lib`, algorithms such as `sort` have been respecified such that they are not allowed to copy `value_type`.  So it actually is safe to sort a sequence of `auto_ptr<T>` now (using `std::sort`).  However `std::unique_ptr<T>` completely replaces the functionality of `auto_ptr<T>`, and `auto_ptr<T>` is still dangerous to use in generic code that **does** use copying (`unique_ptr<T>` fails to compile when used in such generic code).

So `unique_ptr` is safer to use than `auto_ptr` because it refuses to compile when used with generic code that copies.

Answer (score 0):

They don't need to use copy operations anymore in the vast majority of cases. Move-only types like unique_ptr are first-class citizens. That's why move semantics is such a great improvement for both performance and correctness.